# Do I need to use htmlspecialchars after using urlencode inside href or src attribute value?

Tags: php, html

Is it necessary to use htmlspecialchars after calling urlencode like this code:

```
<a href="file.php?var=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(urlencode($var)) ?>">Click here</a>
```

Or can I just write this:

```
<a href="file.php?var=<?php echo urlencode($var) ?>">Click here</a>
```

Comment: yes of course. why you're asking?

Comment: Can you provide an example where it's not secure to just use urlencode without htmlspecialchars?

Comment: it is not about "examples". it's about following the rules. every html output should be html encoded. A very simple rule which is very simple to follow.